# Access SQL to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

This query works in MS Access:

```
SELECT 
       Firm.Adm_Firm_ID, 
       Firm.CCIS_Firm_Seqn_Nbr, 
       Firm.Firm_Name, 
       Firm.Dba_Firm_Name, 
       OHA.File_Closure_Date, 
       OHA.Adm_Qual_Flag,
       OHA.Firm_FY_End_Date,
       OHA.Report_Received_Date,
       OHA.Cognizant_Letter_Flag, 
       OHA.Audit_Type, 
       Firm.AQ_Flag,
       IIF(OHA.File_Closure_Date>=DATEADD("m", -18, Date()),"Yes","No") AS Relevant
FROM 
      dbo_Adm_Firm AS Firm 
INNER JOIN 
      dbo_Adm_OHA_Rate AS OHA ON Firm.Adm_Firm_ID = OHA.Adm_Firm_ID
WHERE 
      ((OHA.File_Closure_Date IS NOT Null) AND (OHA.File_Closure_Date>#1/1/2010#))
ORDER BY 
      Firm.Firm_Name, OHA.Firm_FY_End_Date DESC;
```

I tried to do my best to convert it to T-SQL, which I am calling in a batch script.

```
SELECT 
      Firm.Adm_Firm_ID, 
      Firm.CCIS_Firm_Seqn_Nbr, 
      Firm.Firm_Name, 
      Firm.Dba_Firm_Name, 
      OHA.File_Closure_Date, 
      OHA.Adm_Qual_Flag, 
      OHA.Firm_FY_End_Date, 
      OHA.Report_Received_Date, 
      OHA.Cognizant_Letter_Flag, 
      OHA.Audit_Type, 
      Firm.AQ_Flag, 
      IIF(OHA.File_Closure_Date>=DATEADD(m, -18, GETDATE()),'Yes','No') AS Relevant
FROM 
      dbo.Adm_Firm AS Firm 
INNER JOIN 
      dbo.Adm_OHA_Rate AS OHA ON Firm.Adm_Firm_ID = OHA.Adm_Firm_ID
WHERE 
      ((OHA.File_Closure_Date IS NOT Null) AND (OHA.File_Closure_Date>'1/1/2010'))
ORDER BY 
      Firm.Firm_Name, OHA.Firm_FY_End_Date DESC;
```

The output I get for this in the excel file is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server CH-IS-DB1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.

So I believe the problem is in the `DATEADD` method, but I just can't figure out what the difference is. I tried changing `Date()` to `GetDate()` and changing string delimiters. Any tips?

Comment: Tip number 1 - add whitespace to increase readability.

Comment: Tip number 2 - each part in separate line, comment lines to the point where it works, troubleshoot that line

Comment: I've edited your question for better _readability_. Accept the changes or make it more easy for the eyes by yourself :)

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT 
      Firm.Adm_Firm_ID, 
      Firm.CCIS_Firm_Seqn_Nbr, 
      Firm.Firm_Name, 
      Firm.Dba_Firm_Name, 
      OHA.File_Closure_Date, 
      OHA.Adm_Qual_Flag, 
      OHA.Firm_FY_End_Date, 
      OHA.Report_Received_Date, 
      OHA.Cognizant_Letter_Flag, 
      OHA.Audit_Type, 
      Firm.AQ_Flag, 
      CASE 
      WHEN OHA.File_Closure_Date >= DATEADD(m, -18, GETDATE()) THEN 'Yes'ELSE 'No' END AS Relevant
FROM 
      dbo.Adm_Firm AS Firm 
INNER JOIN 
      dbo.Adm_OHA_Rate AS OHA ON Firm.Adm_Firm_ID = OHA.Adm_Firm_ID
WHERE 
      ((OHA.File_Closure_Date IS NOT Null) AND (OHA.File_Closure_Date>'1/1/2010'))
ORDER BY 
      Firm.Firm_Name, OHA.Firm_FY_End_Date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Are you trying to say I should use `CASE WHEN` instead of `IIF` always?

Comment: In versions prior to sql 2016 it is necessary to use case when, later can use IIF

Comment: Prior to sql Server 2012

Comment: I would also recommend moving your `WHERE` conditions up into your `INNER JOIN`. They filter the OHA table, so it would be more performant to filter out rows you don't need in the `JOIN` rather than letting all those rows combine and then filter. `JOIN` runs before `WHERE`.